# Why do two codes that calculate pi using the same algorithm have different running times?

Tags: python, time-complexity

The Wallis formula is also used to calculate PI. Why are the running times of the two methods so different？

The link to the formula is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product

Thank you so much!
The following code:

```
from __future__ import division 
import time
# Method 1
T1 = time.perf_counter()
pi = 3.14159265358979312
my_pi = 1. 
for i in range(1, 100000):
    my_pi *= 4 * i * i / (4 * i * i - 1.)
my_pi *= 2
T2 = time.perf_counter()
print(pi)
print(my_pi)
print(abs(pi - my_pi))
print("Running time:", T2-T1)

# Method2
T3 = time.perf_counter()
num = 1
den = 1
pi = 3.14159265358979312
for i in range(1, 100000):
    tmp = 4 * i * i
    num *= tmp
    den *= tmp - 1

better_pi = 2 * (num / den)
T4 = time.perf_counter()
print(pi)
print(better_pi)
print(abs(pi - better_pi))
print("The error between the two results:", abs(my_pi - better_pi))
print("Running time:", T4-T3)
```

The following output

```
3.141592653589793

3.141584799578707

7.854011085939305e-06

Running time: 0.04233423100001232

3.141592653589793

3.1415847995787067

7.854011086383395e-06

The error between the two results: 4.440892098500626e-16

Running time: 23.963929412
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242746/discussion-on-question-by-lianghe-why-do-two-codes-that-calculate-pi-using-the-s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second version only uses integers, which are implemented as BigNums, hence much much slower. This is total overkill, unless you hope for huge accuracy (but this is completely hopeless given the very slow convergence of Wallis).

---

By adding this in the loop

```
if i & 15 == 0:
    den= math.frexp(den)[0]
    num= math.frexp(num)[0]
```

here is the output:

```
3.141592653589793
3.141584799578707
7.854011085939305e-06
Running time: 0.033463999999999994
3.141592653589793
3.1415847995786645
7.85401112857187e-06
The error between the two results: 4.263256414560601e-14
Running time: 0.0331592
```

Comment: So if I convert to a floating-point, will it speed up?

Comment: @lianghe: no, it will overflow. (Unless you periodically rescale.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try again.

Comment: Thanks for your unselfish help. I'll try it myself.